# How do I <#include> one Freemarker template into another in NetSuite?

Tags: include, netsuite, freemarker

I'm trying to use Freemarker's [`include` directive](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html) in a template, but no matter how I try to give it the file cabinet path all I get is an UNEXPECTED_ERROR. Does this directive just not work in NetSuite?

Answer (score 3):

It does work, but not with file cabinet paths. There are two options:

1. Use the internal ID of a file in the file cabinet, like this (SuiteAnswer 68965):

   ```
   <#include "563">
   ```

   (Note that the file's extension must be `.txt` or `.ftl`; if NetSuite can't tell that it's a Freemarker file it will refuse to include it.)
2. Include the template by URL. If you're using a file cabinet URL, you have to set the file to Available Without Login.

   ```
   <#include "https://system.na0.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=123&c=12345678&h=1935965101a52f6bf76d&_xt=.ftl">
   ```

   This will also apparently work with any other URL that serves Freemarker templates, though I haven't tried it.